# Removing scientific notation in the tick label of a Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, label

I have made a plot in Matlab, using:

```
hold on
plot(t1,Dx1,'r')
xlabel('t (ps)')
ylabel('Deviation of coordinate from initial coordinate (Å)')
plot(t1,Dy1,'g')
plot(t1,Dz1,'b')
hold off
```

However, the tick labels on the y axis are generated in scientific notation:

[image: Scientific Notation on y-axis]

Is there any way I can remove the scientific notation and just have the y labels range from -0.0025 to 0.0005?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try to manually set the tick labels yourself using sprintf:

```
yt = get(gca,'YTick');
set(gca,'YTickLabel', sprintf('%.4f|',yt))
```

Comment: Argh, you were only seconds faster... ;-). Anyway, you should replace "xtick" and "xticklabel" by "ytick" and "yticklabel". And the x at the end of the second line should read xt.

Comment: :) - was just about to when I got a phone call!

Comment: The x at the end of the second line is still wrong. Should read yt, I guess.

Comment: I found this a horrible workaround, because in case you rescale the figure on screen and the number of tixs on the axes change, you end up with wrong labels.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this after creating the axes:

```
ax = gca;
ax.YAxis.Exponent = 0;
```

Here is an example:

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = 1000*x.^2;

%Plot with default notation:

subplot(1,2,1)
plot(x,y)


%Plot without exponent:

subplot(1,2,2)
plot(x,y)
ax = gca
ax.YAxis.Exponent = 0;
```

Comment: I read dozens of answers, and this one was the bestt !!! Thank you @GHH!

Answer (score 4):

I also fought with getting my plot axes to display in fixed notion instead of scientific notation. The most frustrating part for me was that the "x10^4" label would remain on the edge of the plot box even after I reassigned the tick labels manually to fixed notation. Finally, thanks to the post above I tracked the problem down the figure renderer.  I was using 'OpenGL'. When I changed to 'zbuffer' the "x10^4" label would properly disappear when I manually reset the tick labels.
Here's an example code that apples the format '###,###.0’ to the y-axis labels, and even dynamically updates the y-labels when you zoom/pan etc, thanks to two helpful functions I found on the Matlab File Exchange. The place to find the other two functions is included as comments below example function.

```
function []=TickFixExample()

figure %this one works
myRenderer='zbuffer';
set(gcf,'Renderer', myRenderer); 
axesh = axes();
set(gca,'YLim',[20000 20100]);
title(myRenderer)
ticklabelformat(gca,'y','###,###.0');

figure %this one doesn’t work
myRenderer='OpenGL';
set(gcf,'Renderer', myRenderer); 
axesh = axes();
set(gca,'YLim',[20000 20100]);
title(myRenderer)
ticklabelformat(gca,'y','###,###.0');
```

function ticklabelformat(hAxes,axName,format) by Y. Altman, can be found at:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36254-ticklabelformat-set-a-dynamic-format-of-axes-tick-labels
or by googling 'ticklabelformat matlab'
I modified it slightly by changing line 105 as follows:

```
 tickLabels = arrayfun(@(x)(FormatNumberScalarInputStrOutput`(x,format)),tickValues,'UniformOutput',false);`
```

in lieu of Altman's version:

```
tickLabels = arrayfun(@(x)(sprintf(format,x)),tickValues,'UniformOutput',false);
```

that change provides for the thousands comma separator functionality by
function y = NumberFormatter( Numbers , FormatPattern )  by S. Lienhard, 
also on Matlab File Exchange. My modified version of Lienhard code is
given in full below:

```
function y = FormatNumberScalarInputStrOutput(Number ,FormatPattern)

 % adapted 12-2012 by D. Bourgoyne from NUMBERFORMATTER by S. Lienhard
% 
%   The pound sign (#) denotes a digit, the comma is a placeholder for the
%   grouping separator, and the period is a placeholder for the decimal
%   separator.
%   The pattern specifies leading and trailing zeros, because the 0
%   character is used instead of the pound sign (#).
% 
%   Examples:
%   NumberFormatter(rand(5),'0.000')
%   NumberFormatter(rand(5)*100,'###,###.000') 
import java.text.*
v = DecimalFormat(FormatPattern);
y = char(v.format(Number));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to control the format of tick labels of y axis. This code originates from ticks_format.m .

% Set the preferred tick format here.

```
y_formatstring = '%3.4f';
```

% Here's the code.

```
ytick = get(gca, 'ytick');
for i = 1:length(ytick)
    yticklabel{i} = sprintf(y_formatstring, ytick(i));
end
set(gca, 'yticklabel', yticklabel)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the following:

```
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'zbuffer')
```

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of matlab (2016b) you can use the functions ytickformat and xtickformat to easily change the format of the labels.

Comment: I didn't find any possibility to turn off the exponential notation with this option =(

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work. Even with `%f` which is supposed to be fixed, it still uses a global exponent for the whole axis.