# matlab axes with custom string formatting that scale properly with zoom

Tags: matlab

While trying to enforce a certain type of axis tick label formatting in MATLAB, I happened upon [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10454559/873757) that seemed to work nicely, until I discovered that it was responsible for axes that failed to rescale properly upon magnification/zooming, as demonstrated by running this code sample:

```
h=figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
x=[1E5:1.05E5];
ax=axes('Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.85]);
hold on; plot(x,3*x);
set(ax,'XTickLabel', sprintf('%d|',get(ax,'XTick')));
```

Could anyone suggest a solution that permits both axis tick label `printf`-style formatting and magnification-associated axis tick label rescaling?